# Stock status not showing on WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason, WooCommerce doesn't display stock status on the product page for the simple product.

I have made the settings correctly, you can see on the screenshot:
[Woocommerce Seetings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXM81.png)

And the product page [screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0aJI.png)
The stock status suppose to show [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI5vD.png)

I tried adding following code to function.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_override_get_availability', 1, 2);

// The hook in function $availability is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {
if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('In Stock', 'woocommerce');
return $availability;
}
```

But nothing works! I am using flatsome theme.

Answer (score 0):

Just removed this lines and its working fine now:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 30 );
```